# How to compare a string within a string list in Excel

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, compare, formula

[image: Hi guys, I am trying to write an if statement in Excel but I could not find the right way to make what I need]

There are some food names and prices as you can see between I2 and J22. For instance AYÇICEK YAĞI(SUNFLOWER OIL IN ENGLISH) is 4$ per kg. In the left of the sheet, you can see other list. What I need is;

I want to compare all A* columns with Strings between I2:I22 and get the price which is written between J2:J22 then write it to the D* columns.

There are more than 500 rows and I need to do it for all rows.

And there are some headings as u can see in bold font, they should be protected.

Comment: see [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Also available in [Our 10 most popular functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb).

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped. I wrote =VLOOKUP(A4;Sayfa1!A1:B22;2;0) and it works. But there are some headings in the columns, it causes problems when I try to apply all colums in D*. Do you have an idea to deal with it?

Comment: The formula in your example does not match your picture. Could the issue be, you haven't made `Sayfa1!A1:B22` absolute?

Comment: I have lots of ideas but I do not have the time to type out your sample data in order to proof a solution.

Comment: Hi @Davesexcel. I put the values which were in I2 and J22 to Sayfa1. The thing that I need is; the function will get the price if the string matches. In the other cases, it will not change the value of the column

Comment: It's hard to work with a picture. Especially if you change the question. If possible, upload a sample workbook to googledrive then share a link to it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qd944dtdqc94q4m/Fiyat.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Sorry for my English, I just want to compare strings between the pages urunler and ogle_aksam_gramaj. I want to get the price from urunler's page and write it to the ogle_aksam_gramaj page(under the header which is "FİYATI"). There is nothing more than this. But if string does not match or could not find, the function should not write anything to the column. Just matchcases should be written

Comment: @Mehmet: You can use `VLOOKUP` and it will do the job well. If the items in the price list are unique, AYÇICEK YAĞI for example is something that appears only once in the price list, then you can use `SUMIF`. I will post an answer based on your sheet in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have come up with a formula; now you need a way to dispense it. Your worksheet design does not lend itself to simply filling down a formula. However, with the numbers in column C identifying valid entries that require a formula in columns D and E, a short sub procedure can make quick work of putting the formulas into the correct places.

```
Sub fillFormula()
    Dim w As Long, vWSs As Variant, vFRMLs As Variant

    vWSs = Array("ogle_aksam_gramaj", "kahvalt" & ChrW(305) & "_gramaj", _
                 "araogun_gramaj")

    For w = LBound(vWSs) To UBound(vWSs)
        With Worksheets(vWSs(w))
            With .Columns(3)   '<~~ going to look at column C for numbers
                With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
                    .Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1, 'urunler'!C1:C2, 2, FALSE), """")"
                    .Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=IFERROR(RC4*RC3, """")"
                End With
            End With
        End With
    Next w
End Sub
```

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) has been used to 'wrap' the lookup and mulltiplication formulas. It catches errors and offers alternative results; in this case, zero-length strings that look blank.

The **kahvaltı_gramaj** worksheet causes problems in VBA due to the unicode character. You might try other methods of cycling through the worksheets.

[image: gamaji]

That binary (macro-enabled) workbook is available from my own public dropbox [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Fiyat_Jeeped.xlsb).

Answer (score 0):

In the workbook you have attached, `VLOOKUP` will return `#N/A` when there is no available value.

In Sheet ogle_aksam_gramaj Cell D4 use the following Formula:

`=SUMIF($I:$I,$A4,$J:$J)`

You can then drag it down and it should be giving you the prices based on the details provided in the same sheet (Range I:J)

The good thing (or bad, depends on you) of sum if is that it will return 0 if there is nothing to sum. in your sheet, the items must be unique in the list, otherwise, it will keep summing every instance. So if AYÇICEK YAĞI is there 2 times, it will be summed twice.

You can use Advanced Filter with (unique values only) to make sure that all the ingredients are accounted for and are mentioned only once.

Thanks.